# How to retrieve the folder name of a given dir?

Tags: perl

I have this dir path c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/THE_1 in my script and I need to retrieve the folder name which is two dirs above this.

In my example I need to retrieve the value THE

I tried it with fileparse of the

```
my($datapath) = "c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/THE_1"; 
print " datapath is: $datapath\n";

my($filename, $bpsPath, $suffix) = fileparse($datapath);
```

Here it returns c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/

Any advice?

Comment: I have no knowledge of PERL, so I won't make it an answer, but in most other languages I think I would use a split method to get all folders in array cells, then just drop the 2 last cells and rebuild the path with what's left...

Comment: @ikegami: Rudely nitpicking over the spelling gains us no friends.

Comment: @Andy Lester, That shouldn't have been read with a rude tone but with a humourous one.

Answer (score 6):

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
say dir('c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/THE_1')->parent->parent;
```

Oh wait, I see you just want "THE"?

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
say dir('c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/THE_1')->parent->parent->basename;
```

or

```
use Path::Class qw( dir );
say( (dir('c:/server/THE/BPS_DATA/THE_1')->dir_list)[-3] );
```

Comment: I think my answer was incomplete. Fixed.